# Android one icon for all small - large screens, will it display?

Tags: android, icons, screen

I have a quick question: will it work when I put the same 57px x 57px icon to all drawable-ldpi, drawable-mdpi and drawable-hdpi folders. Will it run on all devices?

in other words if small icon will be visible on big screens or x-large screens.

Comment: Will be visible but icon will look blurry and make your app look like crap.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It will work, but you really **should not use size of 57x57 for any screen size** - scaled down images will look as ugly as scaled up. Better avoid it.

Please read more here: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design_launcher.html (yes, it is an official documentation).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it'll work. But it is good to have all icons. Because it'll be pixelat on large screens.

If you simple put icon in `drawalbe` folder (which is default folder) and you don't have any other folders like hdpi, mdpi, ldpi for all screen sizes. then it'll also be considered for all resolutions/sizes.

Answer (score 2):

It will work. But it will not look well on some screen.